# Conspiracy theory or conspiratorial theory?

Tags: grammar

Should one use conspiracy theory or conspiratorial theory? I notice that “conspiracy theory” is being used at the time, is it correct to use the term “conspiratorial theory” as that is an adjective?

Comment: Without context, it’s like asking whether a driver should turn left or turn right (or whether turning either way is ‘correct’). We can’t say unless you tell us where you want to go. Please supply context. That is, what do you want to express?

Answer (score 1):

"Conspiratorial theory" is technically correct, but is ambiguous, since it's unclear whether the theory is about conspiracies or is itself part of a conspiracy.

"Conspiracy theory", on the other hand, is less ambiguous and has the advantage of being commonly understood.